# SQL Query - Get result with and without specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Hey there :) I'm pretty new to the SQL query topic. I created this query to get posts with type 'course' and their 'course-category' . It is working but I also need the posts without a course-category.
I think I need all posts with `tt.taxonomy ='course-category'` and all posts without this specific taxonomy. Or in other words all posts where this taxonomy with the value 'course-category' doesn't exist. How can achieve this? As soon as I add the marked part I don't get any results...

```
SELECT
p.post_title,
t.name,
tt.taxonomy
FROM wNfVMposts p
LEFT JOIN wNfVMterm_relationships tr
ON p.ID=tr.object_id
LEFT JOIN wNfVMterm_taxonomy tt
ON tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wNfVMterms t
ON tt.term_id=t.term_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
AND p.post_type= 'course'
AND tt.taxonomy ='course-category'
**AND tt.taxonomy IN ('course-category') IS NULL**
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Comment: You can use  `NOT IN`

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want taxonomy to be either `'course-category'` or empty (null). You could do with `AND (tt.taxonomy = 'course-category' OR tt.taxonomy IS NULL)`

Comment: @PajLe I tried it but it makes no difference in my results.

Comment: Are you sure you have NULL data in that column, given that `post_status` is 'publish' and `post_type` is 'course' ? Could you provide the data you're working with, possibly on some [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess by the semantical name-choices of your tables that you need an INNER JOIN to wNfVMterm_taxonomy instead of a LEFT JOIN (so that you can preserve the NULL values on tt.taxonomy for some rows: please check the different result sets you get, one way or the other, for instructive reasons).
Then, you should filter slightly differently on the WHERE clause to pick your desired rows with tt.taxonomy either equal to 'course-category' or NULL.
Last but not least, the GROUP BY clause is not needed at all if your not using aggregate functions.

```
SELECT
    p.post_title
    ,t.name
    ,tt.taxonomy
FROM 
    wNfVMposts p
    LEFT JOIN wNfVMterm_relationships tr ON p.ID=tr.object_id
    LEFT JOIN wNfVMterm_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN wNfVMterms t ON tt.term_id=t.term_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND p.post_type= 'course'
    AND tt.taxonomy IN ('course-category', NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried your solution but unfortunately the results doesn't change. I still get only the posts with have the taxonomy 'course-category'.

Comment: Then maybe you should leave the LEFT JOIN to wNfVMterm_taxonomy. I will edit the answer.